# Is it possible to apply 3D transformations to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, 3d

Is it possible to appl a 3D transformation to an iframe (e.g. in a div)?

[image]

Comment: 3d transform the iframe? or the div inside it?

Comment: 3d transform the whole iframe,possible? and the whole webpage inside, make it just like the picture shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep it seems so that can be done..

Below examples might be helpful :

1 ) Creating 3D animation using "iframe" in HTML5
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd80b9/creating-3d-animation-in-html5/

2) Dont exactly know how it is done but after observing the source i found that the div and iframes are indeed 3D transformed.

Example is here http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/threejs/css3d/

[Developer of the example](https://plus.google.com/113862800338869870683/posts/PnJB9fAQb6z)